# How to split string and map each character into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose i have a string like `'value=sahi'` and i want it like `{1:s,2:a,3:h,4:i}`
is there any function to do like this.

Comment: `_, word = my_string.split('='); my_dict = {i: c for i, c in enumerate(word, 1)}`.

Comment: It's really unfortunate this was closed as a duplicate as the duplicate question is asking about an array, while this is a dictionary - which is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a specific function I know of but you can use dict comprehension:

```
s = "value=sahi"

d = {k+1: v for k, v in enumerate(s.split("=")[1])}

>>> {1: 's', 2: 'a', 3: 'h', 4: 'i'}
```

Comment: `enumerate` can take an optional starting index, so you don't need `k+1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
value = "value=sahi"
value = value.replace("value=", "")

my_dict = {}
counter = 1

for c in value:
    my_dict[counter] = c
    counter += 1

for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Comment: This is quite unpythonic.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: split your given string on `'='`. This separates the part you don't care about and the part you do care about. In Python, we typically use `_` to represent a "don't care".

```
_, word = given_string.split('=')
```

Step 2: Create a dictionary mapping the 1-indexed position to its respective 0-base-indexed character in the string. In Python, `enumerate` creates an iterable of tuples that does exactly this with 0-indexed positions. You can give an optional starting index. In this case, we want to start with one.

```
my_dict = {i: c for i, c in enumerate(word, 1)}
```

You can clearly do this in one line, but I think it's better to be explicit, especially when comprehensions are already magic. :)